# Any way to avoid "android:" statements in Android XML layout file?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Is there any way to avoid hundreds of "android:" statements in an Android XML layout file?  I am new to Android and I find the "android:" statements make layouts very hard to read.  Plus they are a pain to constantly type.

For example, instead of this:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_column="2"
```

I would like to just see this:

```
layout_width="wrap_content"
layout_height="wrap_content"
layout_column="2"
```

Comment: no way to avoid but you can shorten it to "a:"

Comment: Please read about XML namespaces.  They are not an annoyance, they are essential to the expandable nature of Android and clean separation of UI and code.

Comment: Shorting it to "a:" seems to be the best option.  To those who mentioned autocomplete, I am actually more concerned about readability than I am about having to type "android:" over and over.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eclipse (and presumably Android Studio has similar functionality, but I've not used it) you can auto complete layout properties, e.g. if you type w then ctrl + space it will auto complete this to android:layout_width in most instances. You never really need to type the android: part.

I'm not aware of a way to remove the namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

No. That is needed to know it is part of the Android framework. Instead of say a custom style or custom `View`. I've done a little bit of Android coding and it really isn't a big deal.

For example, there is a copy/paste feature which can make it go faster. Also, most IDEs have autocomplete which is very handy.